# Update model field and any other fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Is it possible to update a field and when saving it, it should save other fields with new changes.

For example, I have the below model,

```
class Backup(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_approve=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_bad=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now, my main aim is to just make `is_approve` field `True`. My secondary aim is to update other fields alongside the `is_approve` field, incase the user makes changes before clicking on the `approve` button in template.

```
    @staff_member_required
    def activate_moderation(request, backup_id=None):
        if id:
           vpostmod=get_object_or_404(Backup, id=backup_id)
           vpostmod.is_approve =1
           vpostmod.save()
```

How can I plug in instances of all fields alongside with the save(), in order to make the changes after setting `is_approve` to True.

**UPDATE TO DANIEL'S QUESTION**

The model has a 'Backup' ModelForm. The forms are rendered via Django admin (BackupAdmin) using the same 'backup' modelform.

I passed my button link by invoking the change_form place in my admin/app_name/modelname/ folder.

```
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        backup= self.get_object(request, self.backup_id)
        context.update({'backup':backup})
        return super(BackupAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

And the change form template is like this:

```
  {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
        <div class="submit-row">
         {% if backup.is_approve %} 
            <p>pass</p>
         {% else %}
           <a href="{% url 'activate_moderation' backup.id %}" class="historylink"> <input type="button" value="{% trans 'Approve' %}" name="_approvebutton" /></a>
           <input type="button" value="{% trans 'Reject' %}" name="_rejectbutton" />
          {% endif %}
        </div>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question, I'm afraid. You update other fields in the same way as you do the `is_approve` one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel. This is how it goes. A user submit a post, and it needs to be approved by a staff before going live. The staff views the post submitted in the admin dashboard, and before the staff clicks on the approve button, he change the title of the post and clicks approve which calls the activate_moderation() function. My question is, how to make the new changes added to the title by the staff reflect in the DB. The  activate_moderation() function will only approve the post and not save any changes made to other fields by the staff. Do you get my point?

Comment: I guess so, but there's not nearly enough information here to answer the question. How are the fields being updated? Is there some kind of form? What does the template look like? What is the view that renders that template in the first place?

Comment: Updated my question. pls check it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have several options.

First one is to **overwrite save method** on Backup model:

```
#Backup
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        previous_Backup = Backup.objects.get(self.pk).is_approve
    super(Backup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.pk and self.is_approve != previous_Backup:
        #make changes
```

Second one is **binding function to post save signal +  [django model utils field tracker](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#accessing-a-field-tracker)**:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Backup)
def create_change_backup(sender,instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        previous_Backup = get it from django model utils field tracker
        #make changes
```

Comment: I will try this when I'm back home. Thanks!